# how to convert List<Map<String, String>> into the list containing the values of the map in java8

Tags: java, collections, stream

`List<Map<String,String>>` - this is given

I want to get `List<String>` of values of the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you mean you can do something like this :

```
List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps = ...;
List<String> values = listOfMaps.stream()
    .flatMap(map -> map.values().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

List< String > valuesList = new ArrayList<>(yourmap.values());

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Java-program-to-convert-the-contents-of-a-Map-to-list